# Promedio de campos Text

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

Tengo varios campos tipo texto separados en columnas.

[image: Columnas de la tabla]

Todos son números, mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de sacarles el promedio? porque intente usar el CAST para convertirlos a INT pero no funciono

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente te falló porque tienes campos con valor NULL.
puedes probar con

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(coalesce(<columna>, '0') AS integer))
```

La función Coalesce se queda con el primer valor que no sea null, así que si el valor de la columna es null, se toma el texto '0', que se puede transformar a enterno sin problema.

Comment: Lo intente con la forma en la que me indicas, pero me saca este error: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer, y no me permite hacer el calculo

Comment: es posible que tengas algun valor que no se un numero, revisa si tienes espacios